# What does information on a 2m319J D622 magnetron label imply?

Tags: magnetron

I been looking for a 2m319J D622 magnetron at reasonable $.
I see the D622 also D623 and D625 ,, What do the values imply, I've been
unable to find any info..

Comment: refer to the magnetron datasheet

Comment: So far I have not found any data sheet!!!!